# Browser repainting is several frames behind on high resolution

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, browser

I'm building a website with an infinite grid. You can move the grid by holding right click and moving the mouse.

**How it works:** the grid has a `position: absolute` and I set the `top` and `left` css properties accordingly. For the background lines, I use a `background-position` property. I'm using `requestAnimationFrom` on the mouseMove event.

**My problem:** it works smoothly at 1080p, but the movement lag behind at 1440p. It's not a FPS problem (depite that I have a lower FPS than at 1080p), it's just that if I move my mouse, the grid will move 0.5s behind. Does anyone have an idea how to fix that?

Here's and example of the grid:
[image]

If you guys want to see it for yourself, here's a sample: https://luna-park.app/editor (Just hold right click and move the mouse quickely)

I though it was due to my 244Hz screen: I added a throttle to 60FPS, but no change.

I tried the CSS properties `will-change` and `transform: translateZ(0)` with no luck...

I don't think it's due to my hardware:

- I have a Ryzen 9 7945HX (that can go up to 5.4Ghz)
- I have a RTX4080 (laptop but still)

Comment: Does using another browser change anything?

Comment: @James It's the same thing on both Firefox and Chrome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOUND IT! It was actually all due to my grid background wich used a background-image with a lot of linear-gradient functions.

This must be pretty unoptimized, I'll replace it with a canvas.